# How to properly setup the validation with Spring MVC4 and Hibernate Validator?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I am learning Spring MVC and attempting to add validation to my controller based on the constraints I set for the model. When I am using the `@Range(min=1, max=100)` constraint, as long as I type in a number whether it is in the range or not, it strangely validates to true, otherwise, it validates to false. The validator seems not picking up the `@Range` Annotation I set up on the model. The `minutes` is the field I am validating. Is there anything I did wrong that caused this wrong behavior?

**Goal.java**

```
package io.test.model;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;

public class Goal {

    @Range(min = 1, max = 120)
    private int minutes;

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }
}
```

**GoalController.java**

```
package io.test.controller;

import io.test.model.Goal;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("goal")
public class GoalController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "addGoal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addGoal(Model model) {
        Goal goal = new Goal();
        goal.setMinutes(10);
        model.addAttribute("goal", goal);

        return "addGoal";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "addGoal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addGoal(@Valid @ModelAttribute("goal") Goal goal, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println("result has errors: " + result.hasErrors() + " | " + result.toString());
        System.out.println("Minutes updated: " + goal.getMinutes());
        return "redirect:addMinutes.html";
    }


}
```

**addGoal.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Goal</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form commandName="goal">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Minutes</td>
            <td><form:input path="minutes"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Enter goal minutes">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is OK, But where <form:errors /> to show in case of error

Comment: @user7790438, I thought my code was ok - but the writer in the controller ` System.out.println("result has errors: " + result.hasErrors() + " | " + result.toString());` print out `true` as long as I enter a number, the `@Range` constrains is not picked up. any clue?

Comment: Are you sure that `import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range` what you used.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu yes, I copied my code here, that is the only import statement in my code that reference the `@Range` Annotation.